# How to add multiple floors to a map in a text-based game?

Tags: python, maps, pygame, text-based

I decided to learn how to make games during this quarantine. I am reading Mission Python, a book that teaches how to make games using python and pygame. I'm halfway through it, but the game only has one map.

I'm trying to challenge myself by adding a basement and an upstairs room, but the book doesn't have anything on making multiple floors.

Current code for my map:

```
###############
##    MAP    ##
###############  

MAP_WIDTH = 5
MAP_HEIGHT = 10 
MAP_SIZE = MAP_WIDTH * MAP_HEIGHT

GAME_MAP = [ ["Room 0 - where unused objects are kept", 0, 0, False, False] ]

outdoor_rooms = range(1, 26)
for planetsectors in range(1, 26): #rooms 1 to 25 are generated here
    GAME_MAP.append( ["The dusty planet surface", 13, 13, True, True] )

GAME_MAP  += [
        #["Room name", height, width, Top exit?, Right exit?]
        ["The airlock", 13, 5, True, False], # room 26
        ["The engineering lab", 13, 13, False, False], # room 27
        ["Poodle Mission Control", 9, 13, False, True], # room 28
        ["The viewing gallery", 9, 15, False, False], # room 29
        ["The crew's bathroom", 5, 5, False, False], # room 30
        ["The airlock entry bay", 7, 11, True, True], # room 31
        ["Left elbow room", 9, 7, True, False], # room 32
        ["Right elbow room", 7, 13, True, True], # room 33
        ["The science lab", 13, 13, False, True], # room 34
        ["The greenhouse", 13, 13, True, False], # room 35
        [PLAYER_NAME + "'s sleeping quarters", 9, 11, False, False], # room 36
        ["West corridor", 15, 5, True, True], # room 37
        ["The briefing room", 7, 13, False, True], # room 38
        ["The crew's community room", 11, 13, True, False], # room 39
        ["Main Mission Control", 14, 14, False, False], # room 40
        ["The sick bay", 12, 7, True, False], # room 41
        ["West corridor", 9, 7, True, False], # room 42
        ["Utilities control room", 9, 9, False, True], # room 43
        ["Systems engineering bay", 9, 11, False, False], # room 44
        ["Security portal to Mission Control", 7, 7, True, False], # room 45
        [FRIEND1_NAME + "'s sleeping quarters", 9, 11, True, True], # room 46
        [FRIEND2_NAME + "'s sleeping quarters", 9, 11, True, True], # room 47
        ["The pipeworks", 13, 11, True, False], # room 48
        ["The chief scientist's office", 9, 7, True, True], # room 49
        ["The robot workshop", 9, 11, True, False] # room 50
        ]

#simple sanity check on map above to check data entry
assert len(GAME_MAP)-1 == MAP_SIZE, "Map size and GAME_MAP don't match"
```

Comment: Welcome to Game Development Stack Exchange. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if you're asking to add a new room or a new floor but if you want to add a new room you can simply write in another entry to that large `array` you have there

```
...
["The pipeworks", 13, 11, True, False], # room 48
["The chief scientist's office", 9, 7, True, True], # room 49
["The robot workshop", 9, 11, True, False] # room 50

["basement", 9, 11, True, False] # your first new room
["upstairs", 15, 8, True, False] # your second new room
]
```

If your looking for a whole new floor, if have some sort of [structure](https://python.swaroopch.com/data_structures.html) you're using to store your current game map, you can make an [array](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp) of them to have multiple floors, so something like:

```
GAME_MAP_FLOOR_ONE = [ ["Room 0 - where unused objects are kept", 0, 0, False, False] ]
GAME_MAP_FLOOR_TWO = [ ["Room 0 - where unused objects are kept", 0, 0, False, False] ]
GAME_MAP_ARRAY_OF_FLOORS = [GAME_MAP_FLOOR_ONE,GAME_MAP_FLOOR_TWO]
```

Hope this helps point you in the right direction

Comment: I am trying to add an new room sorry for the confusion. I was thinking i would have to make a dictionary of my map with separate levels. I do not know if that would of worked, but it was an idea. The array looks like it would work, but how would i go in connecting the 3 floors. As far as using a stair case or elevator to load the new floor in the code?

Comment: I would have to see how you do movement between rooms currently... i would suggest using a room [class](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) that can have member variables and methods for moving between rooms and set it up in there

Comment: Thank you for the help. i will check it out.